# Laravel database migration error

Tags: php, laravel, migrate

I am trying to collaborate with other developers on the project that I am working.

I pulled the latest commit by my friend and trying to run the application.
I tried the following command :

```
php artisan migrate
```

but got the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/assuresale/vendor/composer/../guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions_include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/assuresale/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/assuresale/vendor/composer/../guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/assuresale/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
```

I am using Laravel and assuresale is the name of my project.
And the localhost is showing nothing.

And I have already edited the `.env` according to the need.

Comment: Try running `composer dump-autoload` and check if it fixes it.

Comment: those packages are missing thus the error, try to run composer package.json

Comment: @Sandeesh i tried it. didnt work

Comment: @Exprator It didnt work.

Comment: @dawn are you committing the composer.json file? Check if your composer configs are in sync and run `composer install` once. Also it's always a good idea to commit the composer.lock in collaborative development to keep the package versions in sync.

Comment: @Sandeesh Thanks a lot. That worked.

Comment: @dawn no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a migration, not only a script is created in the `database` folder, but the script is also listed in the autoload files, which are ignored by default from git repositories.

Now that you have downloaded the modifications of your coworkers, your autoload files are out of date. update them using:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: This helped but I kept getting other errors. And finally "composer install" solved the issue.